# jQuery in ajax content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#input').keyup(function() {
        $('#output').html($(this).val().replace(/\n/g,'<br/>')); 
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<?php
ini_set("display_errors","On"); 
    echo "<div id=\"UpdateArea\">";
        echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"type here\" onClick=\"ShowPage()\">";
    echo "</div>";
}

?>
</html>
```

And when I push the button it loads this into the UpdateArea Div:

```
<?php

echo "<textarea id=\"input\" rows=\"10\" cols=\"50\" class=\"textarea\"></textarea><br><br><br>";

echo "<div id=\"output\"></div>";

?>
```

But the jQuery wont Work on the Ajax loaded contents :/ So the input won't show up ind the output div.. Why is that?, I'm new to jQuery, so it might be a obvious problem. I would really appreciate some help :)

The Jquery Works fine if I include the script a jQuery on a page for it self and load it.

Kind regards
Juel

Comment: Can you please redirect me to the duplicate please, I have searched, but no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for attaching events to dynamically added elements:

```
$(document).on('keyup','#input',function() {
   $('#output').html($(this).val().replace(/\n/g,'<br/>')); 
});
```

Comment: Hi Milind :)Thanks, but that dont Work either, the most frustrating thing is that even firebug dont give me an error :/

Comment: is this event getting called. try putting alert inside to test.

Comment: alert('Jubiiiiii'); dont give me anything either, so the event is not being called i guess.. But why?

Comment: do you have same ids for multiple textarea

Comment: No its the only input ID i have at all..

Comment: well this should work then.

Comment: I have put the script into the Ajax called content, and then it Works :D Thanks a lot Milind :)

Comment: @Juel: glad it helps juel :)